# Merge Record<string, string> with one key with different type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to have a type in TypeScript which is an object with property `foo` of type `number` and any other property of type `string`?

I tried:

```
type O = Record<string, string> & { foo: number };

const o: O = { foo: 1, bar: 'baz' };
```

but I get

```
Type '{ foo: number; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type 'O'.
Type '{ foo: number; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'. 
Property 'foo' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2B5YBeYAlGBjA9gJwCYA8AzmDgJYB2A5gDTAnnUB8wAZMAN7ABmWWAXMAoBXALYAjGDmABfANwAoBaGDYKJYAITJOPPoICMdcQEMcggOSmAXhdlygA)

I also tried variations like these but they give the same error:

```
type O = { foo: number; } & Record<string, string>;

type O = { foo: number; [key: string]: string; }
```